# How does Bounds affect skin Mesh Render ？

Tags: unity-game-engine

As a beginner of game development, when I checked the Skinned Mesh Renderer in the Inspector panel, I found that I didn't understand the Bounds option very well, so I went to the official documentation, which explained the bounds as follows：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWTtn.png)

However, this explanation still makes me feel ambiguous, because it doesn't seem to make me understand the specific role of bounds, why mesh should be included in the bounds volume, and if not, what effect will it have on skinng?

However, when I went to Google to search for relevant information, it seemed that there was no explanation for the mechanism of bounds at all, only the explanation at the application level. When I'm learning something, I'm more inclined to understand how it works to the best of my ability. So I hope some experts can help explain the function of bounds, thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly from the doc do you not understand? Tbh to me it sounds pretty clear what it's purpose is and it what cases you might have to manually tweak the bounds (they are literary listed there). The bounds are mostly used to determine if your object is currently visible or should be excluded from rendering. Therefore it is important that the bounds more or less match with the actual bounding box volume of your meshes after skinning, animating. If you are only dealing with the default use case you most probably don't have to care about the bounds at all ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks a lot, I actually thought the same thing before, but I wasn't so sure. After a little experimentation in Unity, I'm now sure of my ideas.